# Extracting clause from a Penn Treebank-formatted text

Tags: nlp, stanford-nlp

Say I have a sentence:

```
After he had eaten the cheese, Bill went to the grocery.
```

In my program, I get the following output:

```
---PARSE TREE---
(ROOT
  (S
    (SBAR (IN After)
      (S
        (NP (PRP he))
        (VP (VBD had)
          (VP (VBN eaten)
            (NP (DT the) (NN cheese))))))
    (, ,)
    (NP (NNP Bill))
    (VP (VBD went)
      (PP (TO to)
        (NP (DT the) (NN grocery))))
    (. .)))
```

How would I merge the stuff not within a clause to become an independent clause? Like this:

```
S Clause {
    SBAR Clause {
         After he had eaten the cheese,
    }

    S Clause {
        Bill went to the grocery.
    }
}
```

I'm pretty sure that I'm not clear, but basically I want to extract the independent and dependent clauses of the sentence, and the subclauses of those clauses.

Comment: See this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/10401824/109618

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a demonstration code from the NLTK guide (It doesn't explicitly show how to extract a clause):
http://nltk.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/doc/howto/tree.html

Comment: I don't see how this answers the question. NLTK is a Python tool. The question is tagged as being about Stanford NLP.

Comment: David James- NLTK is a Python tool for, among other things, handling data that is formatted in the structure output by Stanford NLP. There are "corpus reader" classes that can handle formats such as Penn Treebank.

http://nltk.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/doc/howto/corpus.html

Comment: The link in this answer is now password protected

Comment: What is the username and password?