# How to obtain the "Grammatical Relation" using Stanford NLP Parser?

Tags: java, stanford-nlp

I am absolutely new to Java development.

Can someone please elaborate on how to obtain "Grammatical Relations" using the Stanfords's Natural Language Processing Lexical Parser- open source Java code?

Thanks!

Comment: see my answer here- this is for dependency parsing (vs syntactic) but I give some source code too: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10397342/parse-out-phrasal-verbs/10401824#10401824

Comment: Thanks for the response nflacco! I might sound a bit dumb to u but, please tell me how am I gonna use the "GrammaticalRelation.class" in edu.stanford.nlp.trees package? My requirement is to find the grammatical relations amomgst the words in the input sentence.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

See line 88 of first file in [my code to run the Stanford Parser programmatically](https://gist.github.com/2562754)

```
GrammaticalStructureFactory gsf = tlp.grammaticalStructureFactory();
GrammaticalStructure gs = gsf.newGrammaticalStructure(parse);
Collection tdl = gs.typedDependenciesCollapsed();

System.out.println("words: "+words); 
System.out.println("POStags: "+tags); 
System.out.println("stemmedWordsAndTags: "+stems); 
System.out.println("typedDependencies: "+tdl);
```

The collection tdl is a list of these typed dependencies. If you look on the [javadoc for TypedDependency](http://www-nlp.stanford.edu/nlp/javadoc/javanlp/edu/stanford/nlp/trees/TypedDependency.html) you'll see that using the .reln() method gets you the grammatical relation.

Lines 311-318 of the third file in my code show how to use that list of typed dependencies. I happen to get the name of the relation, but you could get the relation itself, which would be of the class GrammaticalRelation.

```
for( Iterator<TypedDependency> iter = tdl.iterator(); iter.hasNext(); ) {
    TypedDependency var = iter.next();

    TreeGraphNode dep = var.dep();
    TreeGraphNode gov = var.gov();

    // All useful information for a node in the tree
    String reln = var.reln().getShortName();
```

Don't feel bad, I spent a miserable day or two trying to figure out how to use the parser. I don't know if the docs have improved, but when I used it they were pretty damn awful.